# Variavel perde o valor após sair da Promisse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

Olá, estou tendo o seguinte problema, eu tenho uma variavel que deve armazenar os dados vindos de uma promisse, para que esses dados possam ser utilizados em outras funções, mas por algum motivo a variavel guarda os dados da promisse somente enquando essa promisse esta sendo executada, após sair dela a variavel volta a ficar como undefined. Estou a ultizar o angular 1 e o Pouchdb.

No PounchDB e possivel pegar um documento JSON apartir de um banco de dados dentro do navegador.

```
   //Varivel que armazenda dados
   var salvaAqui;

   db.get('mydoc').then(function (doc) {
     salvaAqui = doc;
     console.log(salvaAqui); // Retorna resultado esperado.
   }).catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   });

   console.log(salvaAqui); // Retorna undefined
```

Eu só preciso saber como faço para manter os "dados" que a promisse deu a varivel. Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Na verdade, a execução está acontecendo em tempos diferentes. Olhando pelo seu código, é o que dá a entender. A variável tem sim o valor de `doc`, porém você está dando o `console.log` fora da função, portanto antes da execução de `then`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, na depuração o a promisse ta sendo executada antes do console.log do final, e dentro do then já tem um log que retorna os dados normal.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido isso. Na verdade, geralmente usasse funções de promisse para fazer requisições a recursos paralélos (ou assíncronos). Quando você dá aquele console.log no final, sem nada ser retornado, é absolutamente compreensível: a variável ainda não teve o valor do callback de `then` executado. Você tem que entender que em javascript, a ordem do código não significa a ordem em que os resultados serão obtidos. Numa requisição ajax por exemplo, o  fato de dar um console.log depois de sua chamada não mudaria nenhum valor da variável.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters funcionou agora, você realmente estava certo eu que mosquei aqui na hora de depurar. Coloquei minhas funções que utilizam os dados da promisse dentro de outra função que só e chamada dentro do then da promisse, assim deu certo.

Comment: Vou publicar como resposta então

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Obrigado cara, também publiquei a minha solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, a execução está acontecendo em tempos diferentes. Olhando pelo seu código, é o que dá a entender.

A variável tem sim o valor de `doc`, porém você está dando o `console.log` fora do `callback` executado por `then`. Portanto, antes da execução de then, nenhum valor ainda será atribuído a `salvaAqui`.

Geralmente, usa-se funções com promisses para fazer requisições a recursos paralelos (ou assíncronos). Quando você dá aquele `console.log` no final, sem nada ser retornado, é absolutamente compreensível: a variável ainda não teve o valor do callback de `then` executado.

Você tem que entender que em javascript, a ordem do código não significa a ordem em que os resultados serão obtidos. Numa requisição ajax por exemplo, o fato de dar um `console.log` depois de sua chamada não mudaria nenhum valor da variável no mesmo escopo em que foi declarada, mas apenas após a conclusão da requisição.

Exemplo:

```
var dados; // undefined 
$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
     dados = response.data; // [Object Object]
});

console.log(dados); // undefined
```

A sugestão nesse caso é fazer a operação necessária com os dados que você precisa dentro da chamada de `then`.

Algo parecido com isso:

```
db.get('mydoc').then(function(doc) {
    processarDoc(doc); // passa como argumento
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

function processarDoc(doc) {

    console.log(doc); // [Object Object]
}
```

Comment: O cara sabe, me ajudou muito essa resposta, eu tava fazendo uma gambiarra no meu código que nem eu mais tava entendendo o que estava aconteçendo ali.

Answer (score 0):

A promisse é executada após o resto do código, por isso o valor retorna undefined. minha solução foi

```
    //Varivel que armazenda dados
    var salvaAqui;

    db.get('mydoc').then(function (doc) {
    salvaAqui = doc;
    executaResto();
    }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    });

    function executaResto(){
       console.log(salvaAqui); // Agora retorna os dados normal
    }
```

Comment: Adicionei também  um exemplo. Preferi chamar a função passando como parâmetro, ao invés de usar uma variável declarada fora do escopo. Dê uma olhada